# Javascript code for validating jsp form is not Validating

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation

Hello I've a js file in WebContent which has a function validate() to validate code for Signup.jsp in WEB-INF.

1. How to add that function to "onsubmit" in the form?
2. I tried writing the javascript inside the Signup.jsp and called it in "onsubmit = 'return validate'" but its not working.

So plsss someone help me am in need.

This is my Signup form

```
  '<form name="Register" action="RegisterServlet" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtFname" id="fname" maxlength="30"/>
<span id="errorFirstNameMissing" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
<span id="errorFirstNameInValid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide a valid first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLname" id="lname" maxlength="30"/>
<span id="errorLastNameMissing" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
<span id="errorLastNameInValid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide a valid first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender* : </td>
<td><select name = "txtGender" id="gender">
<option value="unknown">Select your Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
<span id="errorMissingGender" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category* : </td>
<td><select name = "txtCategory" id="category">
<option value="unknown">Select your Category</option>
<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>
<span id="errorMissingCategory" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><script type="text/javascript"
src="js/Calendar.js"></script>
<span id="errorMissingDOB" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Age :</td>
<td><input type=text name=txtAge id="ageId" readonly  style="width: 20px;background-color:#D0D0D0;border:none"/>yrs.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address* : </td>
<td><textarea rows="5" name="txtAddr" id="addr" cols="30"></textarea>
<span id="errorMissingAddress" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State* :</td>  
<td> <select onchange="print_city('city',this.selectedIndex);" id="state" name ="txtState"></select>
<span id="errorMissingState" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City* :</td> <td><select name ="txtCity" id ="city"></select>
        <script language="javascript">print_state("state");</script>
<span id="errorMissingCity" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pincode* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtPin" id="pin"/>
<span id="errorMissingPinCode" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
<span id="errorPinCodeInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e-Mail* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="email"/>
<span id="errorMissingEmail" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
<span id="errorEmailInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number : </td>
<td><input type="text"  name="txtStd" id="std" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px"/>-<input type="text" name="txtPhone" id="phone" maxlength="10"/>
<span id="errorStdCodeInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
<span id="errorPhoneNoInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mobile Number* : </td>
<td>+91-<input type="text" name="txtMobile" id="mobile" maxlength="10"/>
<span id="errorMissingMobileNo" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
<span id="errorMobileNoInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;">*Please provide your first name.</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<p>Note: All the fields marked with * are mandatory.</p><br/>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="chkAgree" onclick="EnableSubmit(this)" /> I here by declare that the above data entered by me is true to my knowledge. </p>
<br/>

<div class="style2">
<table>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" id="submit" disabled style="width: 80px;height: 40px">Submit</button></td>
<td><div class="divider"></div></td>
<td><button type="reset" style="width: 80px;height: 40px">Reset</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 </form>'
```

And this is my Java script code

```
function validate(){
var valid = true;
var validationMessage = 'Please correct the following errors:\r\n';
var regex=[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*+$;
var pinRegex="^[0-9]{0,6}$" ;
var emailRegex=/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
var stdRegex="^[0-9]{0,6}$";
var phoneRegex="^[0-9]{0,8}$";
var mobileRegex="^[0-9]{0,10}$";

if (document.getElementById('fname').value.length == 0) {
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - First name is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.visibility='visible';
valid = false;
}
else if(document.getElementById('fname').value!=regex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - First name is not valid can contain only letters from A-z and a-z\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.visibility='hidden';
}


if (document.getElementById('lname').value.length == 0){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Last name is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorLastNameMissing').style.visibility='visible';
valid = false;
}
else if(document.getElementById('lname').value!=regex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Last name is not valid can contain only letters from A-z and a-z\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorLastNameInValid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorLastNameMissing').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('errorLastNameInValid').style.visibility='hidden';
}

if (document.getElementById('gender').value == 'unknown'){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a gender\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.visibility='visible';
valid = false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if (document.getElementById('category').value == 'unknown'){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a category\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if (document.getElementById('SnapHost_Calendar').value.length == 0){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Date of Birth is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingDOB').style.visibility='visible';
valid = false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingDOB').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if (document.getElementById('addr').value.length == 0){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Address is missing\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingAddress').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingAddress').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if (document.getElementById('state').value == 'Select state'||''){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a state\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingState').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingState').style.visibility='hidden';
    }


if (document.getElementById('city').value == 'Select city'||''){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Please select a city\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCity').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else {
    document.getElementById('errorMissingCity').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if (document.getElementById('pin').value.length == 0){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Pin code is missing\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingPinCode').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else if(document.getElementById('pin').value!=pinRegex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Pin code is not valid can contain only digits from 0-6\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorPinCodeInvalid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorMissingPinCode').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('errorPinCodeInvalid').style.visibility='hidden';
}


if (document.getElementById('email').value.length == 0){
validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Email is missing\r\n';
document.getElementById('errorMissingEmail').style.visibility='visible';
valid = false;
}
else if(document.getElementById('email').value!=emailRegex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Email is not valid\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorEmailInvalid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorMissingEmail').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('errorEmailInvalid').style.visibility='hidden';
}

if(document.getElementById('std').value!=stdRegex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Pin code is not valid\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorStdCodeInvalid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorStdCodeInvalid').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if(document.getElementById('phone').value!=phoneRegex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Phone Nummber is not valid can contain digits only from 0-9\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorPhoneNoInvalid').style.visibility='visible';

    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorPhoneNoInvalid').style.visibility='hidden';
    }

if (document.getElementById('mobile').value.length == 0){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  -Mobile number is missing\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMissingMobileNo').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else if(document.getElementById('mobile').value!=mobileRegex){
    validationMessage = validationMessage + '  - Mobile Nummber is not valid can contain digits only from 0-9\r\n';
    document.getElementById('errorMobileNoInvalid').style.visibility='visible';
    valid = false;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('errorMissingMobileNo').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('errorMobileNoInvalid').style.visibility='hidden';
}


if (valid == false){
alert(validationMessage);
}
return valid;
}'
```

Comment: hello i need one more help only my if blocks in the javascript are working. My else if s are not working can u help me.. Even though i provide a valid Firstname its giving error as please provide valid firstname. Same with all the text fields which have else if blocks.. please help me.

Comment: please see update, and remove quotes from the `var regex` declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have typo:

You have declared function where `v` is in `lowercase`.

```
function validate(){
```

and you are calling it in uppercase `V`

```
<form name="Register" action="RegisterServlet" method="post" onSubmit="return Validate()">
```

So try changing your function name or put proper function name in `onSubmit` event of your form.

**Update:**

Try using following line for regex:

```
else if(!regex.test(document.getElementById('fname').value)){
```

Comment: hey awesome its working thanks a lot i dono how i overlooked it thanks a ton... @Bhushan

Comment: @user3222718 you are welcome. Please see point 2 in my updates code.

Comment: ya but i ve a Calendar.js which has SnapHost_Calendar as its id so thats not an issue anyways thanks a lot

Comment: hello i need one more help only my if blocks in the javascript are working. My else if s are not working can u help me.. Even though i provide a valid Firstname its giving error as please provide valid firstname. Same with all the text fields which have else is blocks.. please help me..

Comment: @user3222718 please see update, and remove quotes from the var regex declaration.

Comment: @user3222718 It will be better if you post another question for your new issue. And instead of putting all your code, put only the relevant code.

Comment: ya i did it thank u for the valuable time spent on answering my queries

Answer (score -1):

```
return Validate()
```

should be:

```
return validate()
```